# UCWA Integration for getting Lync Status

Tags: lync, ucwa

I'm trying tointegrateLync using the steps described in the following URL - https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-CreateApplication

When I am implementing the first step I am getting the below response

```
{
    "_links" =     {
        redirect =         {
            href = "https://webdir0A.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root?originalDomain=xxxx.com";
        };
        self =         {
            href = "https://webdirin1.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root?originalDomain=xxxx.com";
        };
        xframe =         {
            href = "https://webdir0A.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/xframe";
        };
    };
}
```

But from the Referenced URL I should get

```
{
  "_links":{
    "self":{"href":"https://lyncweb.contoso.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root?originalDomain=contoso.com"},
    "user":{"href":"https://lyncweb.contoso.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=contoso.com"},
    "xframe":{"href":"https://lyncweb.contoso.com/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame"}
  }
}
```

From this response I have to use the "user" key for second step. But I am not getting this "user" key.

Is anything missing or wrong in the integration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat your request on the "redirect" URL. Though, beware that UCWA is not supported on the cloud - see this thread [MSDN UCWA Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/99d2d572-84ea-41dc-8f8c-c2ad37a7d05e/ucwa-integration-for-getting-lync-status?forum=ucwebapi)